# Is there any example of using Spring Reactive to read through all documents of an ElasticSearch index?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is there any example of using Spring Reactive to read through all documents of an ElasticSearch index?
I want to avoid Reactive repository though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an entity `Entity` and have a `ReactiveElasticsearchOperations` autowired then

```
Flux<SearchHit<Entity>> flux = operations.search(Query.findAll(), Entity.class);
```

and just consume the flux.

Comment: Can you please share the code to consume the flux, assuming that there will be only a single thread available (the same one which runs operations.search()), and also, a callback function needs to be invoked for each document returned by the flux? After the callback executes, the document should become eligible for Garbage Collection.

Comment: If you do not know how to process a flux I'd suggest you first read about reactive programming basic with Spring.

Comment: Following gives only 10 records but I am sure that there are more: flux.doOnNext( (searchHit) -> { hitNumber.getAndIncrement(); LOGGER.info("hit#" + hitNumber); })
.doOnComplete(()->LOGGER.info("DoOnComplete() ran...")) .blockLast();

Comment: Also I want to know whether this internally uses ElasticSearch scrolling feature (that returns scroll ids to the client), or it uses some other method and can still return all the docs (that may be more than (say) 50,000) ?